# PHP & SQL - Uma tentativa de conexão falhou - XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

Iae galera, meu problema é o seguinte. Possuo minha maquina com uma localhost MySQL, nela existe um website que criei, porém, quando tento me conectar a DB do site com outra maquina que não esteja conectada a minha rede WI-FI o acontece o erro:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Uma tentativa de conex�o
>   falhou porque o componente conectado n�o respondeu corretamente ap�s
>   um per�odo de tempo ou a conex�o estabelecida falhou porque o host
>   conectado n�o respondeu.

**Este erro ocorre apenas em computadores externos**, apesar de funcionar tudo normal no meu PC e em outros que estão conectados a minha rede WI-FI.

PHP de conexão do site:

```
define('HOST', '192.168.1.244:3306');
define('USUARIO', 'monty');
define('SENHA', '[senha]');
define('DB', 'login');

$conexao = mysqli_connect(HOST, USUARIO, SENHA, DB) or die ('Não foi possivel conectar!');
mysqli_select_db($conexao, 'login') or die (mysql_error());
```

Alguns passos que já executei:

=> As contas sql possuem permições para fazer a conexão.

=> Já adicionei a conta com o host "%" para qualquer ip.

=> O bind address do my.ini do MySQl está com o IP 0.0.0.0

=> O IP que utilizo no php de conexão é o meu ipv4.

=> Já permiti o mysql e o apache no firewall, apesar do mesmo estar desligado.

=> Os serviços Apache e MySQl estão ligados.

=> O usuario de login da conexão php tem permições globais.

=> Já adicionei as linhas "Require all granted" no arquivo httpd.xampp.conf

Print das contas da localhost:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Todo o código PHP está sendo usado no PHP Desktop e depois convertido em um executável pelo Inno Setup.

De qualquer forma, obrigado pela paciência!

Comment: bind 127.0.0.1 não seria o correto?

Comment: 1. Seu serviço MySQL está ligado e ativo ? 2. Você possui algum firewall bloqueando a porta 3306 ? 3. Você definiu as contas de usuários e o usuário que está utilizando para conectar tem permissões para isso ? 4. O servidor que você está tentando conectar está na lista de servidores permitidos no MySQL ?

Comment: Verifica também, o que realmente deve ser o problema, a ambiguidade que o sistema escuta "localhost", se houver, comente um deles e teste novamente.

Comment: já liberou no firewall o acesso a essa porta ?

Comment: @EliseuB. Não tenho certeza mas o bind 127.0.0.1, é apenas para o acesso local e não possibilita acesso remoto de outras maquinas

Comment: @EliseuB. 1. Sim 2. Não 3. Apenas adicionei permições para que eles possam conectar 4. Não verifiquei isto ainda

Comment: @EliseuB. Desculpe mas como posso fazer isso? Sou novo com MySQL

Comment: @Bulfaitelo Sim, mesmo o firewall estando completamente desativado

Comment: Roda esse comando `telnet ip_do_servidor 3306` e me manda o print do resultado.

Comment: Faz o teste como sugerido pelo Bulfaitelo e posta o resultado

Comment: @Bulfaitelo

telnet 192.168.1.244 3306:

`Y

 5.5.5-10.1.37-MariaDB*q}?bNB?áWwqQ!OJd8-u(mysql_native_password

Conexão ao host perdida.`

Comment: @Nithogg esse teste foi feito em uma segunda maquina na mesma rede ? ou na mesma maquina do servidor ?

Comment: @Bulfaitelo Este foi na mesma do servidor

Comment: @Nithogg agora faz o mesmo teste em uma maquina na mesma rede.

Comment: @Bulfaitelo `Y
5.5.5-10.1.37-MariaDB);.t!Dp?á~_BheEeM2Q!Mmysql_native_password

Conexão ao host perdida.`

Comment: Antes de continuar o teste, explica melhor aonde está e essa maquina, ela está fora da sua rede ? ou está na mesma rede (mesma faixa de ip) ?

Comment: @Bulfaitelo A maquina do segundo teste é um notebook que está conectado na mesma rede e mesmo local do PC host. O IP da segunda maquina é praticamente igual ao da maquina principal.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89891/discussion-between-bulfaitelo-and-nithogg).